# How to make my uiimageview static when i have a scrollview associated with it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating a music application which has more than 12 songs made of 12 tabs .i have added a uiview to my main view and to that uiview i have added imageview which keeps on changing after every 5 seconds. Below that uiview i have added another uiview and imageview and to that my tabs are called dynamically.Scrollview is applied to my tabs .but when i scroll my tabs it gets applied to the whole main view and the imageview that changes after every 5 seconds also scrolls with my tabs that is a problem.Only my tabs should get scrolled and my imageview that changes after every 5 secs should remain static.Please anybody help me regarding this problem.It is urgent.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean with "my tabs are called dynamically", are you using a UITabbarController or it is a custom component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add you imageview to view that contains scrollview instead of adding it to scrollview.